# Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute(while trying to install SXA for 9.2)

Tags: sxa, installation, sitecore-install-framework, sitecore-mvc

I am trying to install the `SXA` package for `9.2` in my *local*. After sometimes of loading it is showing this error. And ended up with package installation failed error.

```
Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute

Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:


[InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.]
   System.ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException(ExceptionResource resource) +60
   System.Collections.Generic.Enumerator.MoveNextRare() +14495363
   System.Web.Routing.RouteCollection.GetRouteData(HttpContextBase httpContext) +300
   Sitecore.Mvc.DeviceSimulator.Pipelines.HttpRequest.HandleSimulationRequest.Process(HttpRequestArgs args) +123
   (Object , Object ) +14
   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +490
   Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists) +236
   Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain) +22
   Sitecore.Web.RequestEventsHandler.OnPostAuthenticateRequest(HttpContextBase context) +214
   Sitecore.Nexus.Web.HttpModule.‌‮⁯‪‎‮‎⁬‎⁯⁬‍‏⁪‬⁫⁯‎‫‏‭‮⁬⁭‬‏‌⁬‭‬⁫⁪‎‌⁮‏‬‬⁭‮(Object , EventArgs ) +414
   System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +218
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) +182
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +94

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.8.9220.0
```

Kindly drop your solutions here!!! Thanks

Comment: Share you logs for more detailed errors please

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are having issues with the wrong version compatibility. I suggest you should check the correct SXA version compatible with your Sitecore 9.2 version.

The version you should install is SXA 1.9, See the compatibility table here.

https://support.sitecore.com/kb?id=kb_article_view&sysparm_article=KB0180187

Second, check the .net framework compatibility also. For Sitecore 9.2, it is .NET 4.7.1 & 4.7.2.

Check the details here.

https://support.sitecore.com/kb?id=kb_article_view&sysparm_article=KB0087164

Hope this will solve your issue.